# Swig - vector of custom objects as return argument

Tags: python, vector, swig

If I have a c++ function like this...

`int myfunc(int a, std::vector<float> *b);`

And I have this in my .i file...

`%apply std::vector<float>* OUTPUT {std::vector<float>*};`

Then in python I can do this...

`_,bout = mylib.myfunc(1)`

and `bout` will be a list of floats just like I want....yay!

But now I want to do this in c++...

`int myfunc(int a, std::vector<MyObj> *b);`

Simply doing the following does NOT work...

`%apply std::vector<MyObj>* OUTPUT {std::vector<MyObj>*};`

It gives ma a wrong type or number of arguments error in Python.  I found a less-than-ideal way to make it work by adding this to my .i file...

```
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
    %template(vectormyobj) vector<MyObj>;
}
```

Then in python I can do this...

```
bout = mylib.vectormyobj()
_ = mylib.myfunc(1,bout)
```

In this case `bout` is a list of my custom types and everything works great....*EXCEPT* I really want to get `bout` on the left hand side of the = instead of having to pass it in as an argument.  It seems like I need some %typemap(in) and/or %typemap(argout) Swig-fu to make it work but I have been unable to wrap my brain around it.

Can anyone provide guidance?

Answer (score 0):

At long last I figured out how to make this work...

First, to be more relevant to my example, let us assume that MyObj is actually in some namespaces so that we access it like `MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj`.  So the function to be wrapped looks like...

```
int myfunc(int a, std::vector<MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj> *b);
```

Then in my .i file I do this...

```
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) std::vector<MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj>* {
    // Create a persistent object to hold the result;
    $1 = new std::vector<MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj>;
}
%typemap(argout) std::vector<MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj>* (PyObject* tmp) {
    // Store the persistent object in a PyObject* that will be destroyed
    // when it goes out of scope.
    tmp = PyList_New($1->size());
    for(auto i = 0; i < $1->size(); ++i) {
        PyObject *junk;
        junk = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new MyNamespace::MyProject::MyObj((*$1)[i])), 
            SWIGTYPE_p_MyNamespace__MyProject__MyObj, 
            SWIG_POINTER_OWN);
        PyList_SET_ITEM(tmp, i, junk);
    }
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, tmp);
}
```

Swig automatically creates the `SWIGTYPE_p_MyNamespace__MyProject__MyObj`...just note where there are single underscores and where there are double underscores!

Now in Python the following works as expected...

```
_,bout = mylib.myfunc(1)
```